# Why out in System.out not capitalized?

Tags: java

Out in `System` class is a `final static` member of type `PrintStream`.

But then why is out not capitalized as the [code conventions by Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/codeconventions-135099.html)?

Comment: Because it is neither a compile time constant nor immutable?

Comment: Because it's a field; fields, even public static fields, start with a lowercase letter by convention.

Comment: @BoristheSpider True, but the `System` streams are so weird that they get special-casing in the JLS itself.

Comment: @chrylis yeah - they're very odd special cases. I guess all the more reason not to name them as constants?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Sure, but worth an explanation as far as the scope of this question is concerned.